# Unable to connect to the remote server when aplication run on windows server 2008

Tags: c#, webclient

```
            WebClient zzz = new WebClient();
            WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("62.162.6.11:3128");
            wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            zzz.Proxy = wp;

            zzz.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
            Byte[] BytesMessage;
            BytesMessage = zzz.DownloadData("http://www.google.com");
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

            StringMessage = UTF8.GetString(BytesMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(StringMessage);
```

I have simple code above when running locally everything is OK i can retrieve html code and do staff , but when i compile and place on a server i always receive Unable to connect to remote server error.  Program is started under administrator account, and server browser (IE, FF) can open page that i request in consloe application, also i  try to turn off firewall, again same error. I'm not sure what permissions are making problems i think i already try everything i can thing of.. Any suggestion...

Comment: wonder if this line is giving you the problem `wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;` I bet you need to pass a username / password. try something like the following `wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");`

Comment: i can remove this part, and also same error. I place proxy just to test if i'm blocked from the web server where i retrieve data. No Mather if i place web proxy or not always when app is uloaded to server give same error.

Comment: have you tried it using the NetWorkCredential() method. ?

Comment: Just added when starting locally again is ok but on server Unable to connet to remote server

Comment: you sounds like authentication issue can you contact your system admin if it works locally but not on the remote server perhaps they have something setup that blocking..

Comment: Not Sure if this can be case of lack of memory on server? or too busy server?

Comment: I just looked at your question again and the only thing I can thing of is Proxy settings on the server itself.. but it's really hard to tell when one does not have direct access to the server.. what if you were to ping the IP address and try your code using the name of the server vs the IP address for the proxy

Comment: with same code instade conslole app i made a aspx page and run on the server and this is what i receive as error from aspx page: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: There are different authentication measures taken from a console App vs a Web Application you would need to contact your system Admin and find out what you need to do or change to make sure that your Web Application can access the new work or your code proxy properly

Answer (score 1):

In this case seems problem is slow/bad internet connection on the server. I just put code in loop if error unable to connect to server occur then run same code again (2 to 5 times), and  usually  from 2 to 3 times code will connect to server receive data  and do the rest of the job. Thanks for the help.